# twitter api response different in salesforce than when done outside

Tags: json, twitter

I'm calling the Twitter APIs with the request:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/67418441/tweets
```

When I submit through postman, the result is structured as follows.

```
  "data": [
    {
      "created_at": "2021-06-17T21:37:04.000Z",
      "id": "1405640664373624832",
      "text": "bunch of text"
    }
  ]...
```

However, when I submit the same request through Salesforce the resulting json is structured as below.

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": "1405640664373624832",
      "text": "bunch of text"
    }
  ]...
```

Notice that the "created_at" tag is missing.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks,

**Here's the code...**

```
string ep = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/users/67418441/tweets';
string BearerToken = 'BearerTokenGoesHere';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint( ep );
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + BearerToken);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setTimeout(120000);
HttpResponse response = new http().send(req);
string ret = response.getBody();
system.debug(ret);
```

**Here's the full JSON payload that it returns,**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1405640664373624832",
      "text": "RT @DisneyD23: NEW: @JimGaffigan on making #PixarLuca, working on Peter Pan &amp; Wendy, and his hilariously complicated relationship with Disn…"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405617299902517250",
      "text": "RT @DisneyParks: As the first guests step through the gates of Disneyland Paris, we mark the celebrated return of magic made at our theme p…"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405601136703283202",
      "text": "Open the door to new storytelling ✨ The Last of the Chupacabras, one of six Disney @LaunchpadShorts, is now streaming on @DisneyPlus. https://t.co/fVTrX3IYXe"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405586038932873231",
      "text": "Suit up with Tony Stark!  The Marvel Cinematic Universe blasted off in 2008. Stream Iron Man on #DisneyPlus. #DisneyDecades https://t.co/pfagtTXjKm"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405570956115038214",
      "text": "Nemo has been the hide-and-seek champ since 2003! Just keep searching, searching, searching for him!  #DisneyDecades https://t.co/Q8Fnec44MY"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405513742431887365",
      "text": "Experience The Beatles: Get Back, a three-part @DisneyPlus Original documentary series streaming November 25, 26 and 27. https://t.co/tcf6BnSqop"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405294962460139520",
      "text": "Here’s to 5 years of magic at Shanghai Disney Resort! ✨ https://t.co/yHNJZzVGLQ"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405268950473129985",
      "text": "Catch up on everything you need to know about the cast of #PixarLuca before you stream the movie on @DisneyPlus this Friday! https://t.co/W6A5CLU9G7"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405253973741875209",
      "text": "https://t.co/bZqBCAA2QL"
    },
    {
      "id": "1405253911896854533",
      "text": "Darling, fabulous style starts with simplicity. \n\nSee #Cruella in theaters now or order it on #DisneyPlus with Premier Access. Additional fee required. https://t.co/CWEXEkwjh5"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "oldest_id": "1405253911896854533",
    "newest_id": "1405640664373624832",
    "result_count": 10,
    "next_token": "7140dibdnow9c7btw3z0ry32z06q03mfyleldy9v8o84z"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you parsing the response in apex?

Comment: This is just looking at the raw json payload that comes back from Twitter.  Later I  parse it using code generated by http://json2apex.herokuapp.com.

Comment: There should be such a property. We'd need to see your code to know more...

Comment: looking at twitter's [api documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets), it doesn't seem like `created_at` is returned by default. Just `id` and `text`.

Comment: Thank you!  @KrisGoncalves for catching the dumb-ass question.  DIdn't form the request correctly when switching from Postman.  Apologies for wasting your time!